# Wear OS swipe-to-dismiss

Tags: android, swipe, wear-os, wearables

I'm developing an app for Wear OS.

It has 2 screens, both extending from `AppCompatActivity`, both having`android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout` as the root of their layouts.

From the first one i can navigate to the second one and in the second screen use left-right swipe to navigate back without problems, i didn't need to do anything for this to work.

For the first screen the same left-right swipe is not doing anything, and i can't understand why, as the documentation says:

> An activity automatically supports swipe-to-dismiss. Swiping an activity from left to right results in dismissal of the activity, and the app navigates down the back stack.

Witch makes sense after seeing the default behaviour of my 2nd screen.

I've tried to put a `SwipeDismissFrameLayout` as the root element of that screen, that make the swipe work, but, instead of showing the watch face that is below, it's showing a gray screen and it's also not finishing the activity (unless i explicitly do it implementing the callback)

From what i can understand in the docs this should be working without having to do anything, but for some reason it's not...

Both activities have the same style and same layout root element.

Is there something i'm missing to make this work?

Comment: It'll only do it automatically if there is a back stack, ie there's another Activity to swipe back to.

Comment: That makes sense, but then how can i achieve the behaviour i'm seeing in all other wear apps? They show the watch face behind and return to it on swipe

Comment: You probably want a transparent Activity, or a floating one. And you seem to have the right idea with implementing the callback and finishing the Activity.

Comment: using SwipeDismissFrameLayout would do it if i can make it show the watch face behind... but this is a very common thing, there should be an easy and standard way of closing and app to return to the watch face...

Comment: Welcome to Google.